# NotFoundHttpException in RouteCollection using proxy reverse and balancing

Tags: php, laravel, azure, load-balancing

I got a web app laravel 5 with nginx server. I'm going to show the balancing configuration:

Proxy reverse configuration

https://system1.example.com/sales aims to http://192.168.4.101:81

https://system2.example.com/sales aims to http://192.168.4.102:81

balancing configuration (through azure)
https://system.example.com/sales aims to https://system1.example.com/sales
                                 or
                                 aims to https://system2.example.com/sales

Now when I use the browser, I put on address bar:

https://system1.example.com/sales    // It works

https://system2.example.com/sales    // It works

https://system.example.com/sales    // It's not working. It refers to route / (root)

https://system.example.com/sales/js/example.js  // It works

The picture attached show the detail of error.
[image]

I see it fails when laravel tries to route the controller, but it works when the url is about a
specific file like example.js. Both web app are the same. The route list are the same.
I don't know how laravel process the routes

What can I do?